# How would one in R apply a "for" function with "if" statements on a matrix to create a smoothing function

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix, apply

So here is my problem:

I have a huge csv file with a lot of data points. Each row represents values belonging to an experiment.

```
       col1 , col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, ..., coln-1, coln
exp_1  190    10000  845   20    100   67   ..., 2       634
exp_2    3      567   87   465   23    867  ..., 987     43
   .
   .
   .
```

Each experiment can be represented in a histogram, but the values need to be smoothed by the mean of their four neighbours. So for example the value 845 at the `matrix[1,3]` will be overwritten by `mean(matrix[1,1]:matrix[1,5])`.
The problem that occurs is at the position `matrix[1,1]`. Because there are no left neighbours the smoothing doesn't work and throws an error. 
Since the columns represent a circular dimension ranging from `0°`to `360°` the values at `coln` actually represent the left neighbour of `col1`.

If I extract the vector of `exp_1` of the matrix (`x=matrix[1,]`) and take this as the input argument for the following code, everything runs smooth.

```
for ( i in 1:length(x)){
  if (i < 2) {
    x[i] = mean(c(x[i:(i+2)],x[(length(x)-i):(length(x))]))
  } else if (i >= 2){
    x[i] = mean(x[(i-2):(i+2)])
  } else if (i > (length(x)-2)){
    x[i] = mean(c(x[(i-2):i],x[1:abs(length(x)-(i+2))]))
  }
}
```

Since my matrix has a ton of experiments, I want to loop over the matrix and not single handedly pull out every single row and run my script on it.
So I tried writing my script into a function, looking like this:

```
smoothing_function = function(x){
for ( i in 1:length(x)){
  if (i < 2) {
    x[i] = mean(c(x[i:(i+2)],x[(length(x)-i):(length(x))]))
  } else if (i >= 2){
    x[i] = mean(x[(i-2):(i+2)])
  } else if (i > (length(x)-2)){
    x[i] = mean(c(x[(i-2):i],x[1:abs(length(x)-(i+2))]))
  }
}
}
```

Then I wanted to `apply(matrix,1,smoothing_function)` which results in `NULL`.
I also tried `mapply(smoothing_function,matrix)` which results in `NULL` for each column of the whole matrix.

I think the problem is located within the `length(x)`part because the input argument is not a vector but the single element. Therefore the function can not calculate the mean of any neighbours since the length of the single element is just `1`.

So either I need to generate a vector for each experiment out of the matrix or I need to modify my function. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possibility to avoid the loop and the `if` conditions is to create a new matrix where you paste the last two columns in the beginning and the first two columns at the end.

Here is a small example. First, I create some toydata using `rpois`:

```
set.seed(1)
my_matrix <- matrix(rpois(20, 10), 2, 10)
colnames(my_matrix) <- paste0("col", 1:10)
my_matrix

     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
[1,]    8    7   14   11   14    8    8    7   11    12
[2,]   10   11   12    9   11    2   10   12   12    10
```

This matrix is then extended by adding columns at the beginning and at the end:

```
my_matrix2 <- cbind(my_matrix[, 9:10], my_matrix, my_matrix[, 1:2])
my_matrix2
     col9 col10 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col1 col2
[1,]   11    12    8    7   14   11   14    8    8    7   11    12    8    7
[2,]   12    10   10   11   12    9   11    2   10   12   12    10   10   11
```

Finally, you can use the `rollapply` function from the `zoo` package to compute a running mean. Note that you have to install the `zoo` package first.

```
my_matrix_smooth <- t(apply(my_matrix2, 1, function(z) zoo::rollapply(z, width = 5, FUN = mean)))

     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
[1,] 10.4 10.4 10.8 10.8 11.0  9.6  9.6  9.2  9.2     9
[2,] 11.0 10.4 10.6  9.0  8.8  8.8  9.4  9.2 10.8    11
```

To check that this is correct we can (e.g.) look at `col10` of the first row.
The smoothed version should be `(7+11+12+8+7) / 5 = 9`. And this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I did not know about the `rollapply` function in the `zoo` package. Is there a way one could do the same thing without having to refer to another package? I suppose I could just copy the function from the source code to my routine.

Comment: @hoyohayo, yes you could try to look up the code but it would be easier just to refer to it :)